# Can you use regular expressions in struts-config.xml?

Tags: java, struts, struts-config

I'm trying to route these two url's to different Actions.  We are using Struts 1.2:
/abc-def/products
/abc-def

I tried putting this action first:

```
<action path="/abc*/products" type="com.business.exampleAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/go"/>
</action>
```

and then this one after:

```
<action path="/abc*" type="com.business.differentExampleAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/goElsewhere"/>
</action>
```

but it always goes to the second action (differentExampleAction in this case).
I've tried various iterations for the *, like .* or (.*), but haven't found anything that actually works yet.

From what I've read, it seems like the only regular-expression-like characters allowed in struts-config are the wildcard symbols (* and **), but I hope I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you are correct about the wildcard in Struts 1.x... you cannot have anything after `*`. See [documentation section 4.10](http://www.jajakarta.org/struts/struts1.2/documentation/ja/target/userGuide/building_controller.html). This is one of many limitations of Struts 1.x... granted, it is one of the first Java MVC frameworks that works (obviously with some kinks now), which is the reason I decided to switch to Spring MVC 3.x because it allows me to do more Rest-like URI, for example:

```
/abc/product/{productId}/part/{partId}
```

I just don't see how this can be easily accomplished in Struts 1.x.

Comment: I have actually found that you can use regular expressions in struts-config.  They don't work exactly they way you expect, but they do work.  I had to create a bunch of tests to make sure that when I edit struts-config it doesn't destroy my site.  But it seems to be holding together for now, until we move to a newer framework.